# How to use libchamplain to load local tiles or OSM XML in Python?

Tags: python, gtk, openstreetmap, glib, libchamplain

I am trying to use GTK and libchamplain to display a map from local map data. The application is to be run on computers with no internet connection.

After taking a look at the [`mapbox.py`](https://github.com/GNOME/libchamplain/blob/master/demos/mapbox.py) example it seems like one should replace the `NetworkTileSource` source with `FileTileSource`. So I used the [`minimal.py`](https://github.com/GNOME/libchamplain/blob/master/demos/minimal.py) example to work with FileTileSource:

```
widget = GtkChamplain.Embed()
widget.set_size_request(640, 480)

tile_source = Champlain.FileTileSource.new_full(
        ID,
        NAME,
        LICENSE_TEXT,
        LICENSE_URL,
        MIN_ZOOM,
        MAX_ZOOM,
        TILE_SIZE,
        Champlain.MapProjection.MERCATOR,
        Champlain.ImageRenderer())

tile_source.load_map_data("map.osm")
widget.get_view().set_map_source(tile_source)
```

Unfortunately, when running the application, the map is not being displayed, and I receive the following error message:

```
(minimal.py:26308): libchamplain-WARNING **: NULL pixbuf
```

Based on some C examples ([one](http://blog.mikeasoft.com/2010/09/24/local-map-rendering-and-route-finding-with-libchamplain-spatialite-and-open-street-map/), [two](https://github.com/GNOME/libchamplain/blob/master/demos/local-rendering.c)), I assume that there is a so-called renderer missing, called Memphis, which is C only. It seems like Champlain's ImageRenderer, despite its similar name, is not the right tool for this.

So my question is how I would continue at this point. There are quite a few OSM renderers besides Memphis, probably some written in Python as well, but which one(s) would integrate well with Champlain?

It doesn't have to be be OSM, either. A collection of pre-rendered PNG would be fine with me, too. It's just that the [FileTileSource documentation](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Champlain-0.12/classes/FileTileSource.html#Champlain.FileTileSource.load_map_data) specifically mentions "Loads the OpenStreetMap XML file at the given path", which is why I assume better support for OSM.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: did you solve your issue?

Comment: @mariotomo nope.

Comment: what about now? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it in a very simplistic way: just organize your tiles respecting the `#z#/#x/#y#` logic [as described in the docs](https://developer.gnome.org/libchamplain/unstable/ChamplainNetworkTileSource.html#champlain-network-tile-source-set-uri-format), then don't change anything in that [mapbox.py](https://github.com/GNOME/libchamplain/blob/master/demos/mapbox.py) example except the URI.  your case, for a file structure on the `/tmp` directory could look like:

```
    MAX_ZOOM,
    TILE_SIZE,
    Champlain.MapProjection.MERCATOR,
    "file:///tmp/tiles-#Z#/#X#/#Y#.png",
    #"https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/#Z#/#X#/#Y#.png?access_token=" + ACCESS_TOKEN,
    Champlain.ImageRenderer())
```

still according to the docs, the FileTileSource is meant for using a single osm file.  I'm not so sure how that works, I didn't yet try it.